# What happens when two apps define same BroadcastReceiver class in their manifest?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

I have a Android Library project with a BroadCastReceiver class and a scheduler class which defines methods for setting a repeating PendingIntent for the BroadcastReceiver

```
//delay for AlarmManager setRepeating method in seconds
//id as requestCode for PendingIntent
public static void scheduleBroadcast(Context context,int delay,int id){
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SuperReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(KEY_DELAY, (long)(delay * 1000));
    intent.putExtra("APP_NAME", context.getPackageName());
    long timeGap = (long)(delay * 1000);

    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            System.currentTimeMillis() + timeGap, timeGap,
            alarmIntent);
}
```

The Receiver

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e("Chirag-Library","SuperReceiver Received!");
    long delay = intent.getLongExtra(BScheduler.KEY_DELAY, -1);
    Log.e("Chirag-Library","Delay is "+delay+" ms");
    Log.e("Chirag-Library", "By App called  "+ intent.getStringExtra("APP_NAME"));
    Log.e("Chirag-Library",context.getPackageName());
}
```

I am using this project as a dependency in two of my apps which define the receiver in their manifest in the exact same way

```
        <receiver android:name="com.chirag.library.SuperReceiver"/>
```

I call scheduleBroadcast() from both of my apps with different delay value.

In com.chirag.appone

```
BScheduler.scheduleBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 10,111);
```

In com.chirag.apptwo

```
BScheduler.scheduleBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 60,999);
```

Is OnReceive() called for both the apps when any one of the PendingIntent is fired?

Is it because the PendingIntents have same receiver Intent?

Logcat shows the logs in OnReceived fired at the same time seconds

```
09-21 10:04:19.746  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ SuperReceiver Received!
09-21 10:04:19.746  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ Delay is 10000 ms
09-21 10:04:19.746  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ By App called  com.chirag.appone
09-21 10:04:19.746  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ com.chirag.appone
09-21 10:05:06.987  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ SuperReceiver Received!
09-21 10:05:06.987  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ Delay is 60000 ms
09-21 10:05:06.987  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ By App called  com.chirag.apptwo
09-21 10:05:06.987  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ com.chirag.apptwo
09-21 10:06:04.427  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ SuperReceiver Received!
09-21 10:06:04.427  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ Delay is 10000 ms
09-21 10:06:04.427  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ By App called  com.chirag.appone
09-21 10:06:04.427  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ com.chirag.appone
09-21 10:06:40.666  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ SuperReceiver Received!
09-21 10:06:40.666  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ Delay is 60000 ms
09-21 10:06:40.666  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ By App called  com.chirag.apptwo
09-21 10:06:40.666  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ com.chirag.apptwo
09-21 10:06:40.682  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ SuperReceiver Received!
09-21 10:06:40.682  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ Delay is 10000 ms
09-21 10:06:40.682  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ By App called  com.chirag.appone
09-21 10:06:40.682  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ com.chirag.appone
09-21 10:07:40.766  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ SuperReceiver Received!
09-21 10:07:40.766  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ Delay is 60000 ms
09-21 10:07:40.766  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ By App called  com.chirag.apptwo
09-21 10:07:40.766  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ com.chirag.apptwo
09-21 10:07:40.774  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ SuperReceiver Received!
09-21 10:07:40.774  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ Delay is 10000 ms
09-21 10:07:40.775  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ By App called  com.chirag.appone
09-21 10:07:40.775  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ com.chirag.appone
09-21 10:08:19.745  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ SuperReceiver Received!
09-21 10:08:19.745  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ Delay is 60000 ms
09-21 10:08:19.745  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ By App called  com.chirag.apptwo
09-21 10:08:19.745  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ com.chirag.apptwo
09-21 10:08:19.754  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ SuperReceiver Received!
09-21 10:08:19.754  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ Delay is 10000 ms
09-21 10:08:19.754  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ By App called  com.chirag.appone
09-21 10:08:19.754  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ com.chirag.appone
09-21 10:09:19.742  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ SuperReceiver Received!
09-21 10:09:19.742  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ Delay is 60000 ms
09-21 10:09:19.742  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ By App called  com.chirag.apptwo
09-21 10:09:19.742  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ com.chirag.apptwo
09-21 10:09:19.751  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ SuperReceiver Received!
09-21 10:09:19.751  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ Delay is 10000 ms
09-21 10:09:19.751  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ By App called  com.chirag.appone
09-21 10:09:19.751  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ com.chirag.appone
09-21 10:10:19.843  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ SuperReceiver Received!
09-21 10:10:19.843  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ Delay is 60000 ms
09-21 10:10:19.843  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ By App called  com.chirag.apptwo
09-21 10:10:19.843  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ com.chirag.apptwo
09-21 10:10:19.853  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ SuperReceiver Received!
09-21 10:10:19.853  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ Delay is 10000 ms
09-21 10:10:19.853  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ By App called  com.chirag.appone
09-21 10:10:19.853  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ com.chirag.appone
09-21 10:11:19.971  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ SuperReceiver Received!
09-21 10:11:19.971  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ Delay is 60000 ms
09-21 10:11:19.971  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ By App called  com.chirag.apptwo
09-21 10:11:19.971  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ com.chirag.apptwo
09-21 10:11:19.979  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ SuperReceiver Received!
09-21 10:11:19.979  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ Delay is 10000 ms
09-21 10:11:19.979  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ By App called  com.chirag.appone
09-21 10:11:19.980  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ com.chirag.appone
09-21 10:12:20.065  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ SuperReceiver Received!
09-21 10:12:20.065  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ Delay is 60000 ms
09-21 10:12:20.066  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ By App called  com.chirag.apptwo
09-21 10:12:20.068  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ com.chirag.apptwo
09-21 10:12:20.075  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ SuperReceiver Received!
09-21 10:12:20.075  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ Delay is 10000 ms
09-21 10:12:20.076  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ By App called  com.chirag.appone
09-21 10:12:20.076  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ com.chirag.appone
09-21 10:13:20.165  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ SuperReceiver Received!
09-21 10:13:20.165  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ Delay is 60000 ms
09-21 10:13:20.165  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ By App called  com.chirag.apptwo
09-21 10:13:20.165  14673-14673/com.chirag.apptwo E/Chirag-Library﹕ com.chirag.apptwo
09-21 10:13:20.171  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ SuperReceiver Received!
09-21 10:13:20.171  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ Delay is 10000 ms
09-21 10:13:20.171  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ By App called  com.chirag.appone
09-21 10:13:20.171  14306-14306/com.chirag.appone E/Chirag-Library﹕ com.chirag.appone
```

What is more confusing to me is why the 10s delay from appone is fired only once between 60s delay from apptwo?

What exactly is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

> Is OnReceive() called for both the apps when any one of the
>   PendingIntent is fired?

No.
Here's why:
The Intent fed into the PendingIntent is explicit Intent and thus makes the OnReceive application context specific and hence both apps have their own receiver even with the same name.

> What is more confusing to me is why the 10s delay from appone is fired
>   only once between 60s delay from apptwo?

After some bug research on setRepeating() , I found this https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=161244

which says on API >= 21 setRepeating() interval value is reset to 60s if less than 60s(this is not documented) which happened to be my case.

Hence the first time they seem to fire off at different time intervals(currentTime + 10s and currentTime + 60s respectively) and later both are fired at intervals of 60s.Also setRepeating() does not always yield seconds accurate events so both of my onReceive seemed to fired at the same time leading to the confusion